# Dspace and Solr Date format

Tags: dspace

I wonder if by default dspace make sure that the date issue of a publication is properly formatted when indexing it in solr ?

I check the schema.xml. Hower i'm not sure that the date is handle pretty well in dspace, so far in Dpace schema it is a string. It is not stored as a date in the database. Hence how does Dspace ensure that the date issued are in the right format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, DSpace doesn't check the format. All metadata values in DSpace are strings regardless of field, so the same might apply for other field types. You will see an error message in the DSpace log file when the indexer encounters a metadata value it can't parse.